# Python 2.7 - re.search in txt file not working correctly

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

im having some trouble with getting re.search to work with a txt file. In my .txt file i have a small piece of code that will write a string to the file called "Python 2.7 - Written Through PyCharm" which works correctly. I then want to use a regular expression to verify that the word "Written" exists in the file.

Here is my code:

```
FileOpen = open("default.txt", "r")
FileRead = FileOpen.read()
return_value = re.search(r"\bWritten\b", FileRead)
print return_value
```

After return_value prints then it does not find the desired word and outputs a search failure upon execution :

```
None
```

If i try the same piece of code on a simple string assigned to a variable then the match is found successfully using re.search i:e:

```
string1 = "The fox jumped over the fence"
re.search(r"\bjumped over\b", string1)
```

which results in this output upon execution ::

```
sre.SRE_Match object...
```

But as soon as i start trying this re.search() through reading the contents in a .txt file then it seems to constantly fail with "None". If anyone can tell me where i have gone wrong as that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does `print repr(FileRead)` show? (Also, by convention, names starting with uppercase letters are classes. Use `snake_case` ones for variables.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip , also i made a new module and tried the same code and it worked. The problem was that directly above this code i had called another file.read directly above. Once removing this then the match was found using the code that was shown in my question. I'm guessing it was trying to open and read a file that was already open for reading thus causing the issue. If my theory is correct on why this caused the regex expression to fail, then i can add this to the answer if agreed upon.

Comment: A way to double check the contents of the string being searched is to look at: `return_value.string`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to do this. You could do it easier.

For example :

```
>>> f = open("test.txt", "r")
>>> fr = f.read()
>>> if "lorem" in fr:
...    print "true"
```

> true

Hope it helps.

**EDIT :**

Time tester :

if str in str :

```
t = Timer("""if 'lorem' in open('test.txt', 'r').read(): print 'true'""")
print t.timeit()
```

> 19.9183969498

regex search :

```
t = Timer("""import re
print re.search(r'lorem', open('test.txt', 'r').read())
""")
print t.timeit()
```

> 31.3400061131

**Note** : the timeit() function repeat 1 million times.

**Conclusion** : "if str in str" is far faster.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way of doing this.In very simple cases i could see myself doing this, but i guess the benefit of using a regular expression is that you can add special characters in the pattern, so that the search filter is more easily narrowed down. Also do you know what performs faster, REGEX or the example that you have given me?